# Trying to move apps over to SD Card

Tags: applications, sd-card

What's the best way to move apps on my SD card? Do I have to root? Because It's getting really out of hand with storage. I only have 8GB on my phone.

The only apps that I have installed myself is Portal, WinRar, Spotify, Textra, Tumblr, Facebook, Messenger, and Twitter. If I try to download anything else, it says I have insufficient space. It's really annoying to be limited to that many apps. I use them very frequently, but it's so annoying how I can't even get a little game to play on my breaks because of this limitation.

Running XT1064 5.0.2 w/ 16gb SD Card

Answer (score 0):

Some apps have the ability to store data onto an external SD card.
Just make sure the SD card is formatted first, then check the settings "within" the app itself to see if there's an option to save or move data to the ext SD card.

If I had to guess, I would say Spotify is eating up a lot of your storage memory.
I would start there first and clear out the data from the app via the app manager and then see if the data can be stored on your SD card.

Comment: Still wouldn't let me move it over. Formatted, cleared data, force stopped it. Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'SuperBackup' App from Playstore and move your  apps, contacts, SMS and then move that backup files to external sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

When the apps are developed there is an option whether to allow it to move it to external memory or not. However for most apps you will be able to move them partially (only data in most cases). 
Even the apps on Play store that help you move apps to SD card won't be of much use if the apps aren't allowed to be moved. If you want to move everything to SD card, you would probably have to root your phone. Rooting your phone would give you access to the root directories allowing you to move system and user apps to external memory.